# Show a dialog box when Alarm is triggered

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension which shows a dialog box to the user every hour.
I am new to the world of Chrome extension development.So far, I have managed to create an alarm in chrome which gets triggered every sixty minutes.

Essentially what I want the extension to do is:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(showpopup);

 where showpopup is a function that 
 contains the code to launch a beautiful
 dialog box written in jquery.
```

Manifest.json

```
{
"permissions": [ "notifications",
                 "tabs",
                 "alarms"
    ],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["alert.js"],
    "persistent": false
},

"content_scripts" : [
{
    "matches" : [ "http://*/*" ],
    "js": ["hello.js"],
    "css": [ "hello.css" ]
} ],
```

Background event page.js

```
function SwitchOn()
 {
     chrome.alarms.create('Alarm', {
     periodInMinutes: 1,
     delayInMinutes:  60
    });
 }

 function showpopup()
{
        alert("Inside function showpopup" + Date());

}
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(SwitchOn);

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(showpopup);
```

As you can see, I am currently throwing an ugly alert box every 60 minutes. Instead, I want to show a beautiful dialog box written in jquery. I intend to use a dialog box library like Bootbox which would most likely have a html, css and js files.

I tried to hack my way into creating a box by creating a new window using chrome.window.create to create  hello.html which links to the css and js file. However, the new window created is blank and doesn't show the output of the jquery file. Also, I don't want to create a new window. I want to create a dialog box in the same tab.

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "hello.html", 
                   type:"popup",
                   focused: true, 
                  })
```

Could you suggest how to proceed?

Comment: Why use a library for something that can be done natively? http://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/

Comment: Ahh thanks. I wasn't aware of the <dialog> tags in Html. But how do I get this html file to be opened when the alarm triggers?

Comment: There are several questions about using jquery in a content script.  They should be able to point you in the right direction if you don't want to use `dialog`.

Comment: @Teepeemm : Well my exact query is how do I call this content script when the alarm gets triggered?

Comment: Then I would recommend editing out anything about jquery and creating a beautiful dialog box.  Otherwise, everyone is going to focus on that.  Instead make the question about how to trigger an alert when the alarm triggers.

Comment: @Teepeemm : So I can already trigger an alert when the alarm triggers with the javscript alert("Show message"); function. But the alert is ugly and without any options to tweak it. To make a beautiful box, I would need some CSS or jquery options..unless there is something that I am missing.